# Change variable value in document after some time passes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm quite new to web development and I want to learn new things. I have a mongoose schema (I won't post it because it's in my own language, you won't understand, so I will explain).
So I have things like name, a code, what user created the entry, etc. (irrelevant for my problem).
I have one variable, let's say, Date like this: `type:Date, default: Date.now`. There is another one, `deactivated: {type: Boolean, default: false}`.
I want, for each entry, after 4 weeks pass the deactivated variable to change to true.

I have no idea how to do that. I didn't try anything and I searched on Google but I couldn't find anything.

I'd like you to give me the idea and make me understand how I should do it, and then I will try to build it myself.

Comment: Every time it runs, check the current date. And if the current date is date in the table plus 4 weeks, set the variable to true.

Comment: Every time it runs what? The .find query in the GET route?

Comment: Every time you need that variable for some purpose. What is the purpose of that boolean variable? If you are going to use it to display a message, for example, every time you run the code to send the message to the client, make the check. 

You don't even need the variable, you can just check the current date and see if it is more than 4 weeks later than the date in your table.

Comment: @Kresimir thanks a lot. I will do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking basically can't be done just like that you have 2 ways about going this route.

1. Everytime there is an entry retrieval you can run a mongoose hook such as `pre('find')` that will check if 4 weeks have passed if so then change the deactivated to `true` you can learn more about hooks on [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find)

Something similar to this example - this example was taken from [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find)

```
Schema.pre('find', function() {
  if (!this.getQuery().userId) {
    this.error(new Error('Not allowed to query without setting userId'));
  }
});
```

2. You can run a cron job every day once or twice (depends on your time period) that keeps checking for records which passed 4 weeks of creation and set `deactivated` to `true`

This is a good cron package [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

EDIT: The cron job can be any period, every 10 minutes, 1 hour, 2, 100, etc...

Good luck

Comment: I think I will use the cron package. If I would check everytime a find query is done that would be bad performance-wise. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The cron will work perfectly fine but becareful from race conditions just like what BonSow pointed out. But also the post('find') hook is not that bad. Either way you choose to go, I think take BonSow advice in terms of creating `expiryDate` and then make it an index and in your `cron` always find by `expiryDate = Date.now()`

Comment: And in your model add `expiryDate` to be required with default value and the default value is equal to `Date.now() + the time period you want it to expire in `

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no active "jobs" in mongoose, you cannot change the value in exactly 4 weeks.
What you can (and should do) is create a post-find hook (just read the documentation). This enables you to write code that is executed EACH time a `find`-query has found a document of your schema and your code is executed BEFORE that document is returned to the calling function.
This way it would run like this:
- you create a user with the now-date
- around 5 weeks later the user logs in again
- for accessing the user-document, mongoose needs to to a find-query for that document
- when the find-query has found the user, your custom hook-code is executed
- inside your hook-code you check if the date is more than 4 weeks old
- if it is not 4 weeks old, then you do nothing
-if it IS 4 or more weeks old, then you change the `deactivated` to true, save the document and return the saved document (or the first one retrieved).
Please read about "hooks" in mongoose, this will definitely help you :)