# Why does .pre find query return undefined in this case?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just learnt about pre/post hooks and I wanted to test it. When I try to console.log it (so I can see it is working as I expect) I get undefined. I don't get why.

I tried to change this.nume to this["nume"]. I thought it might work (because in programming sometimes you get unexpected results) even though is the same things. Unfortunately, it didn't work :(

I have this pre hook:

```
someriSchema.pre('find', function(next) {
    console.log(this.nume);
    next();
});
```

and this schema:

```
var someriSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nume: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

(I have a GET route where I do a find query).

Why does it return undefined? I don't get it. Am I doing something wrong?

///GET route:

```js
router.get('/judet/:id([0-9]{2})', middleware.access2, function(req, res)
{
      var title = "Dashboard";
      Somer.find({}, function(err, user)
      {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.render("dashboard", {title: title, id:req.params.id, someri:user});
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: can you please post the GET route or at least the .find() call?

Comment: @BenSower I added the get route.

Comment: Ok, I just saw that you did not want to edit the query, but the document itself, which you can't unless the hooks are document middleware, not query middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'find' [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html), `this` refers to the query being executed, not a document from the collection.

So unless your query includes the `nume` field, `this.nume` will be undefined.

Comment: And how should I change that so it will return this.nume from the document?

Comment: Here's a link with what I'm trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876010/change-variable-value-in-document-after-some-time-passes/53876257#53876257