# How can I retrieve documents' properties from a pre hook?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I posted this question yesterday because I didn't know how to solve my problem.

[Change variable value in document after some time passes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876010/change-variable-value-in-document-after-some-time-passes)

I was told I need to use a pre hook. I tried to do it, but "this" would refer to the query, not to the document. So I couldn't retrieve the documents to check if the 4 weeks passed. (check the question, you will get it)

Because I don't know how to make this .pre('find') to use variables from each of my document (so it checks if the 4 weeks passed) I was thinking about looping through all of them and checking if 4 weeks passed.

```js
router.get('/judet/:id([0-9]{2})', middleware.access2, function(req, res)
{
      var title = "Dashboard";
      Somer.find({}, function(err, someri)
      {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.render("dashboard", {title: title, id:req.params.id, someri:someri});
        }
      });
}); ///get route
var someriSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nume: {type: String, required: true},
    dateOfIntroduction: {type:Date, default: Date.now, get: formatareData},
});

someriSchema.pre('find', function(next) {
    console.log(this.dateOfIntroduction); <- this will return undefined, because this refers to the query, actually
    next();
});///schema and the pre hook. I thought I could use it like this, and inside the body of the pre hook I can check for the date
```

Here's what I am talking about:

```js
router.get('/judet/:id([0-9]{2})', middleware.access2, function(req, res)
{
      var title = "Dashboard | Best DAVNIC73";
      Somer.find({}, function(err, someri)
      {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            someri.forEach(function(somer)
            {
            ///check if 4 weeks passed and then update the deactivate variable
            })
            res.render("dashboard", {title: title, id:req.params.id, someri:someri});
        }
      });
});
```

but I think this will be very bad performance-wise if I will get many entries in my DBs and I don't think this is the best way to do this.

So, if I was told correctly and I should use a pre hook for obtaining what I've said, how can I make it refer to the document?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I understood your requirements. this is what you could do:

```
/*
  this will always set a documents `statusFlag` to false, if the 
  `dateOfIntroduction` was before Date.now()
*/
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
someriSchema.pre('find', function(next) {
  mongoose.models.Somer.update(
   { datofIntroduction: { $lte: new Date() }}, 
   { statusFlag : false})
   .exec()
   .then((err, result) => {
     // handle err and result
     next();
   }); 
});
```

The only problem I see, is that you are firing this request on every find.

Comment: At first glance it seems like it will do the trick. How will it know what "User" is though? As far as I know, the .pre should be inserted before the declaration of the model. So up until that point, User will be undefined. (Am I right?)

Comment: You are completely right, I updated my answer to both fit your schema and also include some lazy initialization directly accessing the model through mongoose.models instead. This way, we'll only access the initilized version of Somer, since this hook will only be called AFTER the server has started and the model was initialized.

Comment: It seems like it's going to work. I can't check it rn, I will do it tommorow. If it works, I will accept it as correct. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: No problem, we ran into a similar problem a while back, trying to assign manually generated IDs to some docs on creation, that's why I still have that hacky snippet flying around.

Comment: "The only problem I see, is that you are firing this request on every find." how can I fix this? Do you have a better alternative?

Comment: I can currently not think of any other logical solution. The only other approach the external script (e.g. a cron job), which periodically runs this query. This is a less accurate solution though, since you might have stale data between cron-runs. You can however try to improve your indexing, to reduce unnecessary overhead of these instructions.

Answer (score -1):

> in query middleware, mongoose doesn't necessarily have a reference to
>   the document being updated, so this refers to the query object rather
>   than the document being updated.

Taken straight from the documentation of [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

I pointed you yesterday to their documentation; but here is a more concrete answer.

```
someriSchema.post('find', function(res) {
  // res will have all documents that were found
  if (res.length > 0) {
    res.forEach(function(someri){
        // Do your logic of checking if 4 weeks have passed then do the following
        someri.deactivated = true
        someri.save()
    })
  }
})
```

What this basically do is for every found schema you would update their properties accordingly, your `res` can have only 1 object if you only queried 1 object. your second solution would be to do the `cron`

**EDIT: This is what you would do to solve the async issue**

```
const async = require('async')

someriSchema.post('find', function(res) {
  async.forEach(res, function(someri, callback) {
       // Do your logic of checking if 4 weeks have passed 
       // then do the following - or even better check if Date.now() 
       // is equal to expiryDate if created in the model as suggested
       // by `BenSow`

       // Then ONLY if the expiry is true do the following
       someri.deactivated = true
       someri.save(function (err) {
            err ? callback(err) : callback(null)
       })
  }, function(err){
     err ? console.log(err) : console.log('Loop Completed')
  })
})
```

Comment: Not a big fan of this solution since you'll have raceconditions with this solution since forEach + save() is probably async and can not really be awaited, right?

Comment: I could do that in the get route, but as I said, I think this is very taxing performance-wise if I got a DB with a lot of entries.

Comment: no it can be awaited especially that save has a callback. The only other option would be the cron. with the callback it can be like this. someri.save(err=>{}) and if you want to wait on the previous document before moving to the next document you would have to plug it in an async loop. There is no way to change a document but based on the requirements, with mongoose. Such support doesn't exist. You can always go back and use something other than .save but it boils down to the same thing

Comment: As far as complexity goes. Yes this is pretty complex, and not an optimal solution but there are ways to make it more optimal, by writing your own hook and your own model. Your question however, wasn't about complexity. Keep in mind that the post('find') will always run regardless whether you implement this solution or no, so here we are just checking and then saving ONLY if needed

Comment: @MuhandJumah True, one could create a chain of callbacks, and await them one after another, but both code and performance wise, this has some codesmell attached. And I disagree that there is no other option but the cron, as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: @BenSower I dont know if it would be a chain of callbacks, I have done it previously. Can you however, explain why performance is bad? and no your code I dont think it would do the job because the requirement is to update the document only if 4 weeks have passed. `$lte` is `less than or equal to` so you are always updating the field if the time is less than or equal to current time. As far as save, the document is already there and being saveed to. Unless I am missing something, I would love to know. And Cheers, best of luck.

Comment: @MuhandJumah To avoid a race condition, you'll have to use a callback, either directly or indirectly using async/await. The best thing you could do, is push all save-promises into an array, call Promise.all on them and then call next (which is the second parameter in a post hook, if you need it). Performancewise, this is not optimal, since the work is done on your backend and not your db, which means you have to fetch all required documents from the db, edit them, and then send them back to the backend, which is usually way slower than a direct edit.

Comment: Concerning my solution: I'd simply calculate and save the expirydate on creation of the object and compare it to Date.now(). This is both more explicit and easier to read as well as more performant, since you not only can do the whole update on the DB instead of your BE, but also don't have to do any extra date calcucation (which would probably be negligible, though). If we can not add another field or recycle the old one, then we'd of course have to use a solution like yours. I'd also try to avoid the cron solution, since it could also give you some sort of a race condition.

Comment: @BenSower Agreed with the race condition, and async/await solution is needed - However, I do disagree with the statement "fetch all required documents from the db, edit them, and then send them back to the backend". Because fetching is happening regardless in order to deliver the document hence the use of a hook, so what I am doing is edit and save (keep in mind it only happens when needed this doesn't always happens!) - Where as in your solution you are doing a full tablescan everytime a user does any kind of `find` operation.  Especially that `datofIntroduction` is not an index.

Comment: I do agree with the use of expirydate on creation as it will simplify negligible calculations agreed. I also agree that cron should be avoided if possible as it can produce other issues especially with a race conditions. With that being said for fun, I will be creating a performance benchmark with 100k record today using both ways because I am actually interested now. If interested in the results let me know and I will post the results back; Otherwise, happy holidays and good luck.

**If interested I edited my solution to solve the async issue; However, I am using the popular async lib**

Comment: Yes, I was always wondering how big the difference between both solutions actually is. Please make also sure that your indexes are set properly to make the results as accurate as possible. Concerning your async solution: This way it looks nicer, but we shouldn't forget to call the next() function, otherwise its results are not going to be awaited either.